# Outlook for Mac - Html Preview does not display

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

Using Outlook for Mac (v16.36).  When using preview pane to read Html email messages, often the message display is cutoff when scrolling.  For example:

[image]

I can open the message and it displays correctly.  I also found a workaround, that if I increase the display size of the message (Command-+), it will redraw the html correctly. (I can revert the size (Command--), but it is still annoying to have to do that.)

Anybody else see this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

If I disable Dark Mode (Outlook => Preferences => General => Personalize => Turn off Dark Mode), then this issue does not happen.

I will contact MS support and let them know.